# In GeoDMS, how can I read large shape files?

Tags: geospatial, geo, geodms

I have problems reading a large shape file in GeoDMS GUI version 7.177.

I'm trying to read the BAG (basisadministratie gemeenten, Dutch municipality administration, a giant geo file) into GeoDMS directly from the Kadaster. It's first been converted from .xml into .csv, then from .csv to .shp (using Python 'shapefile' library). When I make a selection of 10 000 buildings, everything goes well. When I want to read the whole BAG (some 16 000 000 building), however, GeoDMS can't seem to read the entire shape file, after a while the CPU usage is close to 0% and no further progress seems to be made.

Code:

```
/*
This program reads the BAG in .shp format and writes it to .dmsdata format for speedy processing in Minta
*/

container root
{
    unit<dpoint> rdc_base; // RDC stands for Rijksdriehoekscoordinaten, Dutch state coordinate system
    unit<dpoint> rdc    := range(rdc_base,point(300000.0,0.0),point(625000.0,280000.0)); // default rdc: built on doubles

    unit<uint32> bagRead:
        storageName     = 'c:/zandbak/intermediate/bagPND.dbf'
    ,   dialogData      = 'geometry'
    ,   dialogType      = 'map'
    ,   storageReadOnly = 'true'
    ,   isHidden        = 'true'
    {
        attribute<rdc> geometry(polygon):
            storageName     = 'c:/zandbak/intermediate/bagPND.shp'
        ,   storageReadOnly = 'true';
        attribute<string>buildingId;
        attribute<string>status;
        attribute<string>year;
    }

    unit<uint32> bagWrite := subset(bagRead/buildingId==bagRead/buildingId)
    ,   storageName     = 'c:/zandbak/output/bagPND.fss'
    ,   storageReadOnly = 'false'
    ,   dialogData      = 'geometry'
    ,   dialogType      = 'map'
    {
        attribute<uint32>   nr_OrgEntity;
        attribute<rdc>      geometry(polygon)   := bagRead/geometry[nr_OrgEntity];
        attribute<string>   buildingId          := bagRead/buildingId[nr_OrgEntity];
        attribute<string>   status              := bagRead/status[nr_OrgEntity];
        attribute<string>   year                := bagRead/year[nr_OrgEntity];
    }
}
```

I run this code using the batch mode:

```
"C:\Program Files\ObjectVision\GeoDms7177\GeoDmsRun.exe" "C:\repository\vesta\bagpreprocessing\root.dms" /bagWrite
```

As said, this code functions well for 10 000 buildings. However, not for 16M buildings. Is there a way to read large shape files in GeoDMS?

Comment: In the bag tools / make snapshot, similar datasets are written to .fss. Without the actual data, it is hard to say what is going on here...

Comment: What is the filesize of the bagPND.shp and the bagPND.dbf ? A shapefile header contains a 32 bit fileLength field that makes .shp files of more than 2GB  or 4GB ambiguous. Were you able to open the shapefile in qGis ?